# Getting raw HTTP request body in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've followed [this issue](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/459) to get the raw body from a POST in my controller but the body only shows up if the encoding is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. When I test with `curl` I can read the POST body but the body shows up empty when the encoding is set to `text/xml`. In my `router.ex` I have:

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["xml"]
end
```

In my controller I have:

```
def parse(conn, params) do
  xml = conn.private[:raw_body]
  Logger.debug(xml)
  text conn, xml
end
```

In `endpoint.ex`:

```
def copy_req_body(conn, _) do
  Plug.Conn.put_private(conn, :copy_raw_body, true)
end

plug :copy_req_body
```

I'm new to Phoenix and Elixir so I'm not sure how to debug this. Why does the encoding of the HTTP request make a difference to the reading of the raw body data? My application needs to accept `text/xml` and read the request body as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In the [code from here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/459#issuecomment-155671415) the parse method accepts the encoding `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I changed it to this:

```
def parse(conn, "text", "xml", _headers, opts) do
...
end
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 9):

Pretty simple way. Not sure if it's "wrong" or not though.

```
defmodule YourApp.YourController do
  use YourApp.Web, :controller

  def receive_obm(conn, params) do
    {:ok, body, _conn} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn)

    IO.inspect(body)
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like THE way to do it! Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2022 :(